# Using FHIR for inventory

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am looking into applications around hospital inventory systems.  Is it correct to use FHIR for things like surgical equipment?  We have an encounter (that is a surgery) and we want to list all the devices, including

- Manufacturer
- Price
- Item or part number
- Image
- Technical specs
- CAD or Collada file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inventory isn't really in the scope of FHIR which is focused on healthcare-related interoperability.  (Inventory, personnel management, purchasing, etc. aren't really any different in a hospital setting than they are in a bank or a factory.)  That said, if you want to use extensions on resources like Device and/or make use of the Basic resource, it's generally possible to cobble together a conformant FHIR-based solution for pretty much anything if you don't mind the liberal use of extensions.